# await function returns a promise and returns true even if the condition is false | React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, react-functional-component

In my JSX file, I have a function like this.

```
async isPresent () {
    const res = await AsyncFunction();
    if (res) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then using it in a conditional rendering as

```
{  this.isPresent() &&  <div> Content </div> }
```

But this always returns true.

How do I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't return true, it returns a promise, which in itself is _truthy_. You need to wait for the asynchronous result.

Comment: How do i do that in isPresent function?

**{await this.isPresent() &&  <div> Content </div> }** returns a error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
const [isPresentResult, setIsPresentResult] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  this.isPresent().then(res => setIsPresentResult(res))
}, [])

// ...
{ isPresentResult &&  <div> Content </div> }
```

Using Class Component:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isPresentResult: false };
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.isPresent().then((isPresentResult) => 
      this.setState({ isPresentResult }));
  };

  async isPresent() {
    const res = await AsyncFunction();
    return !!res;
  }

  render() {
    return {this.state.isPresentResult && <div> Content </div>};
  }
}
```

Comment: const isPresentResult = this.isPresent().then(res => res);
  console.log('fnc', isPresentResult);
The console fnc returns a promise  =>>>>>>>>
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: false

Comment: @komal Agree. I have fixed answer.. Thank you

Comment: I am using class component. How can we do this there, instead of using hooks?

Comment: used this.state.isPresentResult in render and it works. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have asynchronous logic in render. You need to extract the `present` boolean into a state and make the asynchronous call inside something like `componentDidMount` and then update the `present` state from there.

Refer to the example below:

```js
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(true), delay))

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      present: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    sleep(1000).then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.setState({ present: true });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.present ? "Present": "Not Present"}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```